# Get all spans by class name?

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

This seems really basic to me but I can't seem to get it to work and all the examples I have tried don't work for me. I am simply trying to to get the inner text of all spans on a page with the class name "St":

```
<span class="st">text here</span>
```

Some code:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(Content)
'?
```

Here's what I've tried and it gets jack:

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("//span[@class='st']")
       Dim value As String = node.InnerText
       MessageBox.Show(value)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what finally worked:

```
Dim findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").Where(Function(d) d.Attributes.Contains("class") AndAlso d.Attributes("class").Value.Contains("st"))


        For Each f In findclasses
            MessageBox.Show(f.InnerText)
        Next
```